# Update Panel breaks JQuery Elements

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this Jquery code on my page which works perfectly well after button click. However, after an update panel updates the classes added with jquery is removed and also #block-1 is now visible.

```
<script>  
    $("body").on("click", "#app-nav-dash-2", function() {
        $(this).addClass('current-nav');
        $("#block-1").hide();
     });
</script>
```

How do i stop this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you write your asp code also?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to stop the default behavior of link/button:

```
$("body").on("click", "#app-nav-dash-2", function(e) { //<---pass event here
    e.preventDefault(); // it stops to navigate.
    $(this).addClass('current-nav');
    $("#block-1").hide();
 });
```